# Rails 4: Integrating Disqus

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth-2.0, disqus

I'm trying to figure out how to use the disqus-rails gem in my Rails 4 app. https://github.com/sandric/disqus_rails

The instructions say to include an access token in an initialiser. I can't figure out how to generate an access token. I have setup my app and channel in disqus, but can't find the token.

Where do I go to get the access token for disqus?

Answer (score 0):

To get API keys, go to this link and fill out the form, then click "details" in the top menu to see your keys and tokens: https://disqus.com/api/applications/register/

Disqus uses the OAuth 2.0 protocol for authentication.  You will need your own API keys (or tokens), but you may also be able to store tokens in your database from other Disqus users who have authenticated.  See here for details about how to use the Disqus authentication system: https://disqus.com/api/docs/auth/

Answer (score 0):

You have to get the token in you account and follow this instructions:
https://disqus.com/api/docs/auth/